# Live image proceesing in opencv using react native and flask backend

Tags: python-3.x, react-native, opencv, flask, flask-socketio

I want to process the live video frames from react native android app using flask based server.

What will be the best ways to process and stream the video from app and send and receive the response from server in real time.

Can it be done with Socket or any other solution

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer? I am finding about it right now...

Comment: no, i tried but could not get answers

Comment: I found interesting solution, but I can't draw recatngles and show image from camera
Predication works fine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862669/trying-to-make-a-real-time-object-detection-with-tfjs-and-react-native-always-g